# c++ boost::bind placeholder position

Tags: c++, boost, bind

```
using namespace std;

double func(double a, double b)
{
    return a - b;
}

int main()
{
    double result = (boost::bind(&func, _1, _2))(1,0, 2.0);
    cout &lt;&lt; "a: " &lt;&lt; result &lt;&lt; endl;

    result = (boost::bind(&func, _2, _1))(1,0, 2.0);
    cout &lt;&lt; "b: " &lt;&lt; result &lt;&lt; endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> a: 1
>
> b: -1

I think it is the simplest `boost::bind` example. 
But it acts weird not as I expect.

I'm using boost_1.58_0, gcc 4.8.4. 
Could anybody tell me why those place holders are switched ??

Comment: How are we supposed to know what you expect? Did you mean to type `1.0` not `1,0` ? You're passing `1` and `0` to the bound function, the `2.0` is always ignored.

Comment: OMG !!! this is the worst typo in my life. Thanks Jonathan.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo and are passing three arguments to the bound functor:

```
(1,0, 2.0);
```

This substitutes `1` for the `_1` placeholder, and `0` for the `_2` placeholder, and ignores the third argument, so `func` runs `1 - 0` which is `1`.

For the second call you pass the same arguments, but they are passed to the wrapper functor in a different order so `func` runs `0 - 1` which is `-1`.